# generating dynamic insert query for each changing number fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in database with 44 columns like col1,col2,col3....col44 this value may vary 
 I want to insert data into that table not for all the columns what we have , only for some columns in that table those columns are selected by user at run time and provides value for those columns those values should be placed into respective column in single row what user has selected other column should be empty in that row.

Please help how to write code for this situation.

```html
<?php
include("con_gen.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"> 
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .form-horizontal{
    margin: 40px;
  }
</style>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal"  role="form" method="post" action="" >
<h3> Enter Details</h3>

 <?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")  or die("failed to connect to server !!");
mysqli_select_db($link,"idcard");


$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT value FROM combo1");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
  $array = Array();
  $array1 = Array();
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         //echo "<br> value: ". $row['value'].  "<br>";
          $array[] = $row['value'];
          
     
  # code...
  # code...}
}
print_r($array);
//echo "fffffff";
$sql = "SELECT static_name FROM static_values";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                //echo "<option>" . $row['static_name'] . "</option>";
                $array1[]=$row['static_name'];
                 
                 //echo $source;
               }
               print_r($array1);
              
foreach ($array as $row)
{
  if(in_array($row, $array1))
  {
    $source=Array();
   $sql = "SELECT source_table,Alias_name FROM static_values where static_name='$row'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                //echo "<option>" . $row['static_name'] . "</option>";
                 $source=$row['source_table'];
                 $source1=$row['Alias_name'];
                 //echo $source;
               }
               
               //print_r($source1);
    ?>
     <div class="row-fluid">
               
            <div class="span3 bgcolor">
              <?php echo "<label>".$source1."</label>";?>
              <select  id="static" name="static" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control" >
              <!--<select name="customer_type" id="customer_type"  class="span12"> <option>Type 1</option> <option>Type 2</option>  </select>  -->
                <?php echo "<option>".$row. "</option>";
                 foreach ( $Data->$source as $key =>$item) echo "<option value=".$key.">".$item."</option>"; ?>               
                </select> 
                                                </div>
</div>
<?php
}
      else
 {
    ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
               
            <div class="span3 bgcolor">
             <?php echo "<label>" . $row . "</label>";?>
                 <input id="ggg" type="text" placeholder=" Enter Value " name="text_value" style="width:100%" class="form-control" />
                              
                </select> 
                                                </div>
</div>
    <?php

      # code...
     
  }

}
}
  # code...
?>
<br>
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-success"  name="submit" />
<?php

?>  
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
//include('db.php');
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")  or die("failed to connect to server !!");
mysqli_select_db($link,"idcard");

//$arr=Array();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM combo1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
  echo "ddd";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                //echo "<option>" . $row['static_name'] . "</option>";
                $arr[]=$row['column'];
                //  print_r($arr);
                 
               }
               print_r($arr);
               if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$errorMessage = "";
if ($errorMessage != "" ) {
echo "<p class='message'>" .$errorMessage. "</p>" ;
}

//$ins="insert into `column_list` value($row)";
  $sql = array(); 
foreach( $array as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['static']).'", '.$row['text_value'].')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `column_list` (static,text_value) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
    }    
$test=mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
if($test)
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
else
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
exit();
    
        
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Where are you stuck?  It also seems like your database structure could use some... improvement.  But aside from that, what attempt have you made to write your `INSERT` statement?  What does an example resulting statement look like based on some given input, and how would you determine that statement from that input?

Comment: yaa I have tried for some insert statement but that does nothing i think i was completely  wrong am not getting code for this

Comment: eg database table  :  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6.....col44
    
    user select like this after retrieving:
    col1 varchar name
    col2 varchar state
    col10 varchar address 
    here user selects the columns as how much they want
     after this table we will provide actual value to those name,state
    
    Name :textbox [xyz]
    state :dropdown [abc]
    address :textbox [wer]
    after entering data 
    the above table should be like
    col1 col2... col10...col44
    xyz   abc      wer              
    other column should be empty

Comment: If you show what you tried and explain what went wrong then we can probably help with that.  Currently you're just presenting extremely vague requirements and asking us to write all of your code for you, which isn't really what Stack Overflow does.

Comment: I have uploaded my code in last php snippet"SELECT * FROM combo1"

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are volunteers here. Most of us won't attempt to read more than ten lines of code; please [edit] your question to cut down your code example to only the relevant lines.

Comment: Above  select works properly but data we need to insert into those selected columns that insert query going wrong but i don't  know what is exactly going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I will offer some hints about how to handle this.

First of all, your table definition must allow `NULL` values in the columns which your user may choose to omit.

Second, if you know you need to insert `col3` and `col5` values, and no others, an `INSERT` query like this will do the trick

```
     INSERT INTO table (col3, col5) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Alternatively, you can use a query like this

```
 INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, ... coll44)
            VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, 2, NULL,... NULL)
```

I've used `...` in that example to avoid writing out the names of all columns.

An observation: 44 columns is a lot for a table. It's even worse when the table is sparse (when not all the columns are used). You may wish to investigate using some sort of normalized key/value store instead. You can read about those things.

One of the problems you encounter in SQL when handling sparse rows (where many values are null, and the null values are different in each row) is the **absolute requirement** that you generate your `INSERT` statements dynamically for each situation. You can do that using php. Or, maybe you can do it using stored procedures. But you can't avoid doing it, sorry to say.

Comment: thnx for ur time It's not the answer what I'm looking the above code I can do but it won't work dynamically and also not the way to do please suggest alternate way

Comment: You did ask for advice. You have a **terrible** table design. As you have struggled to figure out how to insert rows to your table, you have learrned why it is a terrible design.